# Azure SQL - Running a stored procedure manually from SSMS takes 16 minutes, running it with logic apps takes > 12 hours

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a stored procedure in an Azure SQL database that does two simple things:

1. Rebuilds indexes based on fragmentation level (once an index gets above a certain level of fragmentation it'll rebuild it).
2. Updates SQL statistics

When I run this manually in SSMS it can take anywhere from 15-30 minutes to run. However, when I run it from logic apps, sometimes it will run just fine, and other times it will run until the timeout I have set (which is 12 hours) then fail. Why would running the procedure on logic apps get stuck whereas running it manually always works?

I'm assuming that the logic app will only fail if there's an index that needs rebuilt because after I run it manually, it seems like the logic app will complete just fine until there's an index that needs rebuilt.

Also, I never had this issue with whatever I was using to run the stored procedure before I had to move it to logic apps since Azure was deprecating whatever I was using before (I can't remember what ran the job last time).

Appreciate any help anyone can provide here or troubleshooting steps. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe using an automation account with some powershell script would work better ? Honestly I haven't tried

Comment: Hi Thomas, I believe I was using that before, then I got an email saying I needed to switch to Logic Apps. I never had this issue when running the stored proc with the powershell script.

Comment: So create an automation account: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro and give it a try :-)